# How can i combine this codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

As the title says, I think this code can be simplified in less lines. Could someone help me with this?

```
    $('a[href=#over]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#over").offset().top - 100
    }, 2000);
});

$('a[href=#diensten]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#diensten").offset().top - 100
    }, 2000);
});

$('a[href=#portfolio]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#portfolio").offset().top - 100
    }, 2000);
});

$('a[href=#contact]').click(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2000);
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

I was thinking myself off an if/elseif statement, but im kinda stuck in there. So could you please have an look?

Comment: have you *tried* simplifying it?

Comment: As a hint, for the first three the selector you're using is equal to the value of the `href` attribute on the element.

Comment: Yes i tried, but as the #top and #contact is different from the other 3 i was stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `href` attribute of anchors for selecting the element by IDs.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var id = this.href;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - 100
    }, 2000);
});
```

---

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.href;
    var scroll = '';
    if (id === '#contact') {
       scroll =  $(document).height();
    } else if (id === '#top') {
       scroll = 0;
    } else {
       scroll = $(id).offset().top - 100;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: scroll
    }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: You might need to add an if statement inside .animate if (id === 'contact') { ... } else { ... }

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't tested. It is just your code that I minified (and optimized a little bit).

```
$('a[href]').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var htmlbody = $('html,body');
    if( href == '#over' || href == '#diensten' || href == '#portfolio' )
    htmlbody.animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 100 }, 2000);
    if( href == '#contact' )
    htmlbody.animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2000);
    if( href == '#top' )
    htmlbody.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("href");

    if(id in {"#over": 1, "#diensten": 1, "#portfolio": 1}) {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100 }, 2000);
    } 
    else if(id === "#contact") {
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2000);
    } 
    else {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000);
      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only consolidating a process, there are countless answers. But in case you need to micromanage targets, you can do something like:

```
function reusable_scroll_anchor( q_ids, q_off ) {
    for( var q_id in q_ids )(function(q_id) {
        $("a[href=#" + q_id + "]").click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + q_id).offset().top - q_off
            }, 2000);
        });
    })(q_ids[q_id]);
}

reusable_scroll_anchor(
    ['over', 'diensten', 'portfolio', 'contact', 'top' ], 
    100
);
```

Though this approach requires some manual tending, it's a reusable snippet for future sites.